# Grid batch editing destory not work on my local system

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendo,
and work on it with grid.
I found this demo from the [kendo web page](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html)
of kendo grid batch editing.

In this demo I am tring to bind my data source.
It works perfectly but only destroys and does not work on them.
I am also trying this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                         var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                 transport: {
                                             destory:  {
                                             url: "<?php echo site_url('search_result_queue/destory_urls_fields').'/'.$id; ?>",
                                             dataType: "json",
                                     }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "id",
                                    fields: {
                                         regex_id: "ProductName",
                                         value: "Race",
                                         event_url:"url"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 430,
                        toolbar: ["create","save", "cancel"],
                        columns: [
                        { field: "key", title: "field", width: 110 },
                        { field: "value", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                        { field: "event_url", width: 110 },
                        { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "90px" }],
                    editable: true,
                    destory:"inline"
                });
            });
```

Can anyone please know me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled the dataSource transport function "destory" instead of "destroy".

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the spelling of destroy. In your code it is "destory" it should be "destroy".